# Trigger/Stored Procedure causing sql error 127 Informix 12.10.FC10

Tags: triggers, informix

I have a table that has a trigger to capture old and new details for every field in the table every time an application user makes an update. A SP is then executed to capture details (user ID, session ID, old and new values, etc) and send an alert email to anyone who may need to know of any changes.
The trigger/SP works most of the time. Occasionally a user tries to update a field in the table (via application) and encounters an error and cannot complete the update. When I try to update the field manually I get an sql error 127. I then need to disable the trigger, make the update, then reenable the trigger.
The same update to the table by a user (different values for the fields, but generally the same update) can work multiple times but only occasionally fails.
What should I be looking for in terms of cause?
This is on Infx V12.10.FC10, but the trigger was written when it was on V11, not sure if that make a difference.

Only way I can seem to circumvent the issue is to disable the trigger, make the udpate manually, then reenable the trigger.

Comment: It sounds as though you are using the SYSTEM statement to send the email.  The system statement returns the exit status from the shell as the status, a the shell reports status 127 if it cannot find the command to be executed.  The shell can also return 126 for "found a file but it was not executable", and 128+signum if the process dies from signal `signum`. You've not shown the code, but it could be that, for some very unclear reason, the shell fails to find the email program sometimes. How do you invoke the email program? If you use `/usr/bin/mailx` or something equivalent, it should be OK.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! I will definitely look into that. I did not write the code, but I do not think it is using mailx.